# How many numbers after the decimal point can you show using R?

Tags: r

I was wondering how far can you print this:

http://www.iheartchaos.com/post/16393143676/fun-with-math-dividing-one-by-998001-yields-a

In R.

e.g: 1/998001

Comment: R uses IEEE 754. So, to answer your question, no more than 16 significant digits.

Comment: Does it have to be in R? A more general purpose language like Python would be my choice.

Comment: Yep, trivial in Python with mpmath.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan trivial in R with mpc :P :)

Comment: The R wiki has [a page on high precision arithmetic](http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=misc:r_accuracy:high_precision_arithmetic) which demonstrates several other ways to do this with R (beyond the cool mpc package Owen showed off).

Comment: glad to see someone else tried this after seeing it on Stack Overflow today

Comment: @andrest gah, should known better. Packages for anything in R right?!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use the [mpc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mpc/index.html) package,

```
# 3000 is the precision in bits
> mpc(1, 3000) / mpc(998001, 3000)
[1] "(1.0020030040050060070080 ...
...
```

Answer (score 13):

Here is a solution that does not require any fancy packages, just base R and a flashback to elementary school arithmetic:

```
longdiv <- function(num,den, limit=3000, spaces=TRUE) {
    i <- 0
    if( num < den ) {
        cat('0.')
        num <- num*10
    } else {
        cat( num %/% den, '.', sep='')
        num <- (num %% den) * 10
    }
    while( i < limit ) {
        i <- i + 1
        if( num < den ){
            cat('0')
            num <- num*10
        } else {
            cat( num %/% den )
            num <- (num %% den) * 10
        }
        if(spaces){
            if( (i %% 30) == 0 ) {
                cat('\n')
            } else if( (i %% 3) == 0 ) {
                cat(' ')
            }
        }
        flush.console()
    }
    cat('\n')
}   


longdiv(1,998001)
```