# How to improve the precison in such a situation in R?

Tags: r, statistics, precision

I want to calculate the value of `(1e-6)^84`, but in R/R64, the result is `0`, which would cause some problem when applying `log10` function on it.

Is there anyway to solve this problem?

Comment: You can probably use the info in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025412/how-many-numbers-after-the-decimal-point-can-you-show-using-r

Comment: Can't you just compute `84 * log10(1e-6) = 84 * (-6) = -504`?

Comment: It's probably overkill, but you could also look into a package like **Rmpfr** that allows for arbitrary precision arithmetic.

Comment: Is there a reason for the `machine-learning` tag?  As suggested/hinted by others here, giving a little bit more context would help you get better answers ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends what problem you are actually trying to solve.  Do you care about the value of log(teeenytinynumber)?   If not,   replace the zero values with NA and keep going.   If you do, figure out if there's a better way than following a giant exponent with a log function.  Which is to say, simplify your algorithm before crunching numbers.